# SharedPreferences is saving only the last value

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

i try to use SharedPreferences but it's only saving the last value.

`MainActivity`:

```kotlin
myPreferences.setPrice(txtPrice.text.toString().toFloat())
myPreferences.setSABV(txtABV.text.toString().toFloat())
```

SharedPreferences handler:

```
class myPreferences(context: Context){

    val PREFERENCENAME = "BeerNote"
    val PRICE = 0.0f
    val ALCOHOLBYVOLUME = 0.0f

    val preference = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCENAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    fun setPrice(price:Float){
        preference.edit().putFloat(PRICE.toString(),price).apply()
    }
    fun getPrice():Float{
        return preference.getFloat(PRICE.toString(),0.0f)
    }

    fun setSABV(abv:Float){
        preference.edit().putFloat(ALCOHOLBYVOLUME.toString(),abv).apply()
    }
    fun getABV():Float{
        return preference.getFloat(ALCOHOLBYVOLUME.toString(),0.0f )
    }
}
```

When i try to recover the data:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Price:"+mypreference.getPrice(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
Toast.makeText(this, "ABV:"+mypreference.getABV(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

It only saves the ABV value in Price and ABV.

Comment: You end up using the same key for both preferences. Your keys shouldn't be float values converted to strings. They should be something like `"price"` and `"alcohol_by_volume"`.

Comment: @MikeM. lol you are right, thx

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use constants as keys instead of floats converted to strings as you do now. This would look like:

```
class myPreferences(context: Context){

val PREFERENCENAME = "BeerNote"
val PRICE = 0.0f
val ALCOHOLBYVOLUME = 0.0f
val priceKey = "price"
val SABVKey = "sabv"

val preference = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCENAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

fun setPrice(price:Float){
    preference.edit().putFloat(priceKey,price).apply()
}
fun getPrice():Float{
    return preference.getFloat(priceKey,0.0f)
}

fun setSABV(abv:Float){
    preference.edit().putFloat(SABVKey,abv).apply()
}
fun getABV():Float{
    return preference.getFloat(SABVKey,0.0f )
}
}
```